# How to find the name of disk volume, and then perform some action if it is equal to a variable?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out. First, to answer what I'm sure will be asked, yes, I need to use a batch script. I'm sure that this is much easier in PowerShell or another language, but it needs to be a Windows Batch Script (CMD). 
I am trying to re-design this script to be used on new systems and older systems within our company. The newer systems use Windows Server 2012, while the older systems use Windows Server 2008. Both systems will have 2 hard drives, but the difference between the 2 is the use of the second hard drive. On the older systems, the 2nd drive is used as a backup drive. On the newer system it is not. 
In layman's terms, here is what I am looking to do:

```
IF ANY DISK VOLUME includes "Backup" in it's name (Caption)
    SET %buletter% to the Drive Letter
    SET other variables
ELSE
    SET the backup location to something else
    SET other variables
```

I've been able to pretty easily able to find how to find the name of the disk volume with the following:

```
FOR /f %%b IN ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^, Label ^| find "%lookfor%"') DO Stuff
```

But I haven't figured out how to wrap the FOR statement in an IF statement.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Some of the older systems may not have a 2nd HDD installed. The issue is that the drive letter is not always consistent. Some have them installed as D: some as E:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for /f "usebackq skip=1" %%p in (`wmic volume where "label like '%%Backup%%'" get Driveletter`) do echo Backup Drive is %%p
```

The only issue - it will give an empty string on a last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use an `IF` initially,

- you can use find and use conditional execution on success `&&` or fail `||` or
- initializing a var and using a for /f to eval the output - and afterwards check if the var is defined.
- I'd exclude the first disk by checking for `BootVolume` in an extended where clause

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\25\SO_54366874.cmd
@Echo off
Set "BackUpDrive="
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2*" %%A in (`
    wmic volume where 'DriveType^="3" AND BootVolume^="FALSE" AND Label like "%%Backup%%"' get DriveLetter^,Label 2^>NUL ^| find ":"
`) Do Set "BackUpDrive=%%A"
If defined BackUpDrive (
    Echo Drive with label Backup found: %BackUpDrive%
    Rem other commands
) Else (
    Echo no drive with label Backup found
    Rem other commands
)
```

Sample output here:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\01\25\SO_54366874.cmd
Drive with label Backup found: D:
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea from @mirGantrophy of checking the OS Version, this is what I came up with.

```
SET Version=
FOR /F "skip=1" %%v IN ('wmic os get version') DO IF NOT DEFINED Version set Version=%%v
FOR /F "delims=. tokens=1-3" %%a in ("%Version%") DO (
    SET Version.Major=%%a
    SET Version.Minor=%%b
    SET Version.Build=%%c
)

IF %Version.Major% LSS 10 GOTO Win2008
IF %Version.Major%==10 GOTO Win2012

:Win2008
FOR /F %%p IN ('wmic logicaldisk where "VolumeName='%lookfor%'" get Caption ^| find ":"') DO (
    SET buletter=%%p
    SET bootdrvltr=C:
)
GOTO SetLocalDrv

:Win2012
SET buloc=C:\Archive
SET bootdrvltr=D:
GOTO SetLocalDrv

:SetLocalDrv
SET localdrv=%bootdrvltr%\Bootdrv
```

Comment: Your methodology is badly flawed because you have not determined which version numbers are relevant to your products. `Windows Server 2008` is `v6.0`, `Windows Server 2008 R2` is `v6.1`, `Windows Server 2012` is `v6.2` and `Windows Server 2012 R2` is `v6.3`. For major version `10` you'd be looking at `Windows Server 2016`!